# Turf operations download result shp, kml, csv, gml

Tags: download, turf, files

I have temporary layers as a result of turf operations and I now I have the options of download as a JSON file, I would like now the option of download it as a shp, kml, csv or gml.

Is or are there any option?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running Turf on a server in [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) can export GeoJSON to most formats. For example, this line would convert a GeoJSON file to a Shapefile:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" cities.shp cities.geojson
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Morgan Herlocker, I have Geoserver running and I solved it implement it in Geoserver, thanks anyway